# Build a tree from a particular node

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, data-structures, treeview

I have tree nodes stored in the database like this

[image]

Then I build this flat structure to the hierarchy structure by using this recursive code

```
    public IList<GuidingNode> BuildGuidingTree(int professionId, int parentId)
    {
         var guidingTrees = _context.GuidingNode.Where(p => p.ProfessionId == professionId).ToList();

         return FlatToHierarchy(guidingTrees, parentId);
    }

    private IList<GuidingNode> FlatToHierarchy(IEnumerable<GuidingNode> list, int parentId)
    {

        return list.Where(i => i.ParentId == parentId)
            .Select((v, i) => new IVTSGuidingNode {
                Id = v.Id,
                ParentId = v.ParentId,
                Title = v.Title,
                Children = FlatToHierarchy(list, v.Id)
            }).ToList();
    }
```

Therefore, It becomes like this

```
- Medical Field
    - General Treatment
        - Having a headache
            - Patient Information
            - Symptoms
            - Giving out medicine
        - Having a cold
    - Specific Treatment
        - Something
```

The thing is what if I would like to get the specific path by a particular node.

For instance, If I passed

> NODE ID 3 "Having a headache" as a parameter to the function (I don't have it yet.)

I would get only its above nodes and beneath nodes. As a result, It would look like this

```
- Medical Field
    - General Treatment
        **- Having a headache**
            - Patient Information
            - Symptoms
            - Giving out medicine
```

The unrelated nodes would be pruned out of the tree.

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this situation. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by "i selected" -> Select in the LINQ sense, or select in the "i click on a node in a TreeView with my mouse" sense? Or something else?

Comment: ahh I meant "if I passed it as a parameter" to the function. I'll update the question.

Comment: Your existing code will walk the tree recursively down and make everything under the passed-in node.. So perhaps you just need an append operation that then walks up the tree from each parent in the list (generated by LINQ); your generated list would be an interim step, and for eacg node in that list, walk up to the root, creating new nodes (unless you find that node in a dictionary indexed by id - in which case add your existing tree to the already-created node's children) until you reach the root

Comment: yes, that's exactly I was thinking but hmm still not quite sure how I'm gonna go with this approach.